# Hide/modify IDs in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, e-commerce

Are there alternatives to number IDs in Rails?

I have an e-commerce web application. Whenever one registers, he can see the ID of his account in the URL. In the same way, when one makes an order, he can see the ID of his order in the URL.

Thus, the critical information about the performance of the application can be easily accessed by competitors. (This has already caused problems.) What can I do to hide the information from users?

I was thinking about increasing all IDs by some huge number, but then one can still measure the performance in some period of time. Also, I will have to modify all the related tables as well.

Is there any way to encode the ID? Or perhaps randomize it somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's a gem](https://github.com/jashmenn/activeuuid) that replaces the standard Rails ids with 16 digit UUIDs. These UUIDs are randomized and "practically unique" (rather than absolutely unique) in that they are just extremely unlikely to be duplicates.

Also, UUID primary key support has been [built in to Rails 4](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/bc8ebefe9825dbff2cffa29ff015a1e7a31f9812).

Besides making the actual number of the ID irrelevant so that a competitor can't count your invoices, etc., because of their universal uniqueness UUIDs are also used to make it easier to combine distributed databases.

> Whenever one registers, he can see the ID of his account in the URL. In the same way, when one makes an order, he can see the ID of his order in the URL.

This is usually a bad practice, and not only for the reason you state. A long number is user-unfriendly in various ways, such as being difficult to remember, type, etc. Using UUIDs make these problems even worse since they're so much longer.

One way to handle this is to create your own unique IDs that are not also the primary key. For instance you could randomly pick an ID for a new account or order, and repick until you find a unique one that can be saved. Then use that number as the display & lookup IDs for those tables.

One neat trick for this is to encode the resulting number as a higher base so that they're shorter, e.g. if you want a pool of 10 million IDs:

```
 rand(10000000).to_s(36)
 => "4s2w1"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mori, for the thorough answer!